# Proper way of creating indexes for same column when "include" columns are different

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

Let's say I have 2 stored procedures and 1 table.

- Table name: `Table_A`
- Procedure names: `proc1` and `proc2`

When I run the `proc1` with execution plan, it suggests me to create an index for `Table_A` for `tblID` (which is NOT a Primary Key) column and suggests to include `column_A` and `column_B`.

And the `proc2` suggests to create an index for `Table_A` again, for `tblID` column but this time it suggests to include `column_B` and `column_C` (it suggests `column_C` instead of `column_A` for this procedure)

So my question is, if I have create an index which included all suggested columns like:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX indexTest
ON [dbo].[Table_A] ([tblID])
INCLUDE ([column_A],[column_B],[column_C])
```

Does that cause any performance issue?

Is there any disadvantage of gathering `INCLUDE` columns?

Or should I create 2 different indexes as:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX indexTest_1
ON [dbo].[Table_A] ([tblID])
INCLUDE ([column_A],[column_B])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX indexTest_2
ON [dbo].[Table_A] ([tblID])
INCLUDE ([column_B],[column_C])
```

**UPDATE:** I would like to add one more thing to this question.

If I do the same thing for primary fields as well:

I mean,

proc-1 suggested to create an index on `tblID` field. And proc-2 suggested to create an index on `tblID` and `column_A`.

If I gather them as :

```
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX indexTest_3
    ON [dbo].[Table_A] ([tblID],[column_A])
    INCLUDE ([[column_B])
```

Does that cause a performance issue? Or Should I create 2 separate index for suggested primary fields?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Definitely create **one** index that includes all three columns!

The fewer indexes you have, the better - index maintenance is a cost factor - more indices require more maintenance.

And the included columns are included in the **leaf level** of the index only - the have only a very marginal impact on performance.

**Update:** if you have a single index on `(tblID, column_A)`, then you can use this for queries that use **only** `tblID` in their `WHERE` clause, or you can use it for queries that use both columns in their `WHERE` clause.

**HOWEVER:** this index is **useless** for queries that use **only** `column_A` in their `WHERE` clause. A compound index (index made up from multiple columns) is only ever useful if a given query uses **the n left-most columns** as specified in the index.

So in your case, one query seems to indicate `tblID`, while the other needs `(tblID, column_A)` - so yes, in this case, I would argue a **single index** on `(tblID, column_A)` would work for both queries.

Comment: is that also same logic for the primary fields as well? I mean one proc suggested to create an index for column_A, and other one suggests to create an index for tblID and column_A. So should I also gather them in primary fields as well?

Comment: @curiousBoy: if this answer helped you understand and/or solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your gratitude for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Comment: sorry I forgot it, I had totally focused on my issue :) Just did it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking at the [missing index dmvs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2007/07/19/are-you-using-sql-s-missing-index-dmvs.aspx). There are a couple things to realize here. The dmvs are really telling you about specific queries or groups of similar where a specific index might help.

In this sense, you are right to combine the indexes. This is the right idea.

However, also remember that indexes have a cost, and it's not the job of this dmv to weigh that cost. You definitely don't want to just automatically create an index to cover every recommendation. You also want to examine these indexes: once you include columns A,B, and C, are you keeping the entire table (or nearly so) in the index? Could you perhaps get better results by changing the primary key to match this index? Be careful evaluating that last part, because changing the primary key could then leave the prior key as an even more important missing index.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Joel Coehoorn